# How to make an attribute case insensitive in Yii

Tags: yii

I have an attribute called 'GroupzDescription'. The column name in DB is groupzdescription. This ambiguity is creating a CException-`Property "Apartment.GroupzDescription" is not defined.`. when it executes the following lines -
 `<?php echo $form->textField($model_apt,'GroupzDescription',array('size' => 60, 'maxlength' => 250)); ?>`

How can I solve this to make this attribute case insensitive.

Comment: In Apartment model I have the GroupzDescription attribute

Comment: @Ninad In database table, it is groupzdescription

Comment: I can but I will be working on a different servers and each of this servers has a different case sensitivity.

Comment: @Ninad In some servers it is GroupzDescription and in some groupzdescription. How to make it case insensitive.

Comment: @Ninad Any suggestions on this

Comment: No idea dude :( on changing the sensitivity rather you should handle this situation in more smarter way

Comment: @Ninad Is there anything I can do using addcondition in Apartment.php

Comment: What are you going to achieve with that it is used to retrieve data from table using condition through sql queries

Comment: You cannot do this, you need to normalize the database structure instead. There are a *lot* of things that are case sensitive both in Yii and in MySQL, and you are not going to fix all of them properly.

Comment: @DCoder Then you say nothing can be done with Yii?

Comment: No, because this is not problem for Yii to solve.

Comment: @DCoder This works fine where it is 'GroupzDescription' but here it is 'groupzdescription' and I'm getting exception

Comment: I have seen some links to solve case insensitivity in posgresql. Is there something similar to that here

Comment: Yes, MySQL can be [configured to be case insensitive](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names) (server-wide, so any other applications running on the server will feel the effect too). But that will just hide your underlying problem instead of solving it. You can go and fix the actual problem now, or you can fix it in two years when you have written five times more code and have ten times more data than you do now.

Comment: MySQL is already configured to be case insensitive.

Comment: @Ninad Just check the new answer

Comment: @DCoder Just check the new answer

Comment: Congratulations. Keep making haphazard tweaks like this, and have fun cleaning up the system when it collapses under its own weight a year from now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved.**
In the model class, I added the below code

```
public function getGroupzDescription()
{
    return $this->groupzdescription;
}

public function setGroupzDescription($groupzdescription)
{
    $this->groupzdescription = $groupzdescription;
}
```

This seems to be working.